# Killing Process using ANT script

Tags: unix, ant, awk

I am trying to kill a process using following ant script

```
<target name="stopappserver">
    <sshexec host="servername"
        username="User"
        password="password"
        command="/local/jboss/hmcs-apps/jboss/bin/stop_hmcs-apps-2.sh"/>
</target>
```

stop_hmcs-apps-2.sh has the following line of code

```
ps -edf |grep `ps -edf |grep hmcs-apps|grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}'` |grep -v hmcs-apps |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill -9
```

When i run ant script I am getting following output and the process is still running. When i run the script stop_hmcs-apps-2.sh directly from the server it works just fine.

```
stopappserver:
[sshexec]    Connecting to WDCDVUA43.hmco.com:22
[sshexec]    cmd : /local/jboss/hmcs-apps/jboss/bin/stop_hmcs-apps-2.sh
[sshexec]    grep: can't open 6503
[sshexec]    grep: can't open 14217
[sshexec]    grep: can't open 6501
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

How can I fix this issue so that I can kill the process using my ant script

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by cleaning up this line:

```
ps -edf |grep `ps -edf |grep hmcs-apps|grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}'` |grep -v hmcs-apps |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill -9
```

This:

```
ps -edf |grep hmcs-apps|grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}'
```

can be written more succinctly as:

```
ps -edf |awk '/hmcs-apps/ && !/grep/{print $2}'
```

and this:

```
ps -edf |grep `whatever` |grep -v hmcs-apps |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill -9
```

can be reduced to remove some of the pipes:

```
ps -edf |awk -v x=$(whatever) '($0~x) && !/hmcs-apps/{print $2}' |xargs kill -9
```

so then your whole line can be written with several fewer pipes as:

```
ps -edf |awk -v x=$(ps -edf |awk '/hmcs-apps/ && !/grep/{print $2}') '($0~x) && !/hmcs-apps/{print $2}' |xargs kill -9
```

so now the only remaining question is - what the heck is it intended to DO???

Calling ps -edf twice and parsing it's output once to use as a grep regexp for parsing it's output again and then excluding some strings from the output....it's all a bit chaotic.

Just tell us what it's meant to do (with some sample input from ps -edf) and we can tell you how to write it.

Comment: Ed, this script was written to kill a process so that we can stop our application server. Here is the grep  
-bash-3.00$ ps -ef | grep hmcs-apps  
hmcs  8320 28865   0 10:55:24 ?           0:00 /bin/sh /local/jboss/hmcs-apps/jboss/bin/run.sh -b dev.hmcs-app.hmhpub.com -c d  
hmcs 29979 29969   0 07:13:21 pts/4       0:00 grep hmcs-apps  
Here in this case the script will kill process ID 8320

Comment: I should have been clearer - update your question with additional information, don't try to provide it in unformatted and text-wrapped comments and again, simply provide the output of `ps -edf` (since that's apparently your scripts starting point) and tell us what you want to do with the specific fields of that output.